# Imprimir un Collection_Select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grails

eh implementado un Collection_Select en mi proyecto rails, me ah quedado a la perfección.

model

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :authors
end

class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :book
  def name_with_initial
    "#{first_name.first}. #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

_form

```
collection_select(:Book, :author_id, Author.all, :id, :name_with_initial, prompt: true)
```

show

```
<p>
  <strong>Author:</strong>
  <%= @book.author_id %>
</p>
```

Eh hecho una migracion donde agrego el campo ***author_id*** a mi tabla ***book***, mi dilema ahora es el siguiente, para mostrarlo en el show, claro esta invocando el campo que agregue que es el **ID**, no solo quiero mostrar el id, tambien todos los datos del author ("*name","last_name","phone","e-mail"*...), supuse que como ya las tenia relacionadas en el modelo probe con :

> @book.author.name y @book.author_id.name

Pero no funciona, no se que agregar al controlador o como mostrar los demas valores correctamente en mi show de book con todos los datos de mi author.

Answer (score 0):

> Ehhh pero se supone que yo al crear el libro, seleccione el autor, es
>   decir un libro tiene muchos autores, solo en este caso ya que es un
>   select, pienso yo, y asi como lo tengo esta funcionando perfecto, solo
>   que tengo problemas al imprimir los datos del autor

Debes cambiar `has_many :author` por `has_many :authors` y en el show:

```
<p>
  <strong>Author:</strong>
  <%= @book.author_id %>
</p>
```

por:

```
<p>
  <strong>Authors:</strong>
  <% @book.authors.each do  |author|%>
    <%= author.id %>
    <%= author.name %>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

Comment: Ehhh pero se supone que yo al crear el libro, seleccione el autor, es decir un libro tiene muchos autores, solo en este caso ya que es un select, pienso yo, y asi como lo tengo esta funcionando perfecto, solo que tengo problemas al imprimir los datos del autor

Comment: respuesta actualizada @STIVENARTEAGAESPITIA

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte, si era un pequeño detalle pero fue que se paso al momento de copiar y editar la pregunta, ya eh encontrado la solucion, muchas gracias, feliz dia.

Answer (score 0):

Ehh bueno eh investigado y eh encontrado la solucion, para hacer un collection_select de este tipo, al momento de hacer la migracion se debe hacer tipo references, asi :

```
> $ rails generate migration AddUserRefToPost author:references
```

Y ahi dentro deberia quedar :

```
class AddUserRefToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_reference :post, :author, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

De este modo esto remplazaria el campo author_id, ya no seria necesario crearlo, rails lo hara por ti y asi se podra imprimir los datos que desees desde la vista(view) de post como normalmente se hace :

```
<%= @book.authors.name%>
```

Y eso es todo...